# How to install Python packages for Orange3 standalone installation

Tags: python, orange

I just tried to find out how to install additional Python packages for the standalone installation of Orange3.

I work on MacOS and want to use the "SQL Table" widget which needs pymysql installed. After installing all add-ons, including Prototypes, the said widget still tells me to "Please install a backend to this widget". This issue remains when pymysql is installed system wide - which by itself is less than ideal and apparently also not the way Orange is intended to work.

I was expecting some click and play install for packages similar to the one for add-ons or some prominently displayed information in the documentation which I failed to find (if it is there).

Comment: Contrary to the the question text, the SQL Data Widget asks for pym**s**sql, not pym**y**sql

Comment: Installation of pymssql required me to first install `Cython` and then use a third party package manager like MacPorts or Homerew to install `freetds` beforehand. Now the `SQL Table` widget only complaining about not being configured to access a database, which is expected. However, I would like to to access MySQL through a local socket, which I still didn't figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install any pip-installable package in the Add-on dialog, if you use the  "Add more..." button.

You can also install packages into the Orange app from a terminal if you run python or pip from the app. On my Mac, I would call `/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/pip` + any arguments. In fact, this is what the Add-on dialog does.

Comment: Hi Marko, I just tried to install pymssql using the first method with no luck. Since it is equivalent to the seccond, I expect no different result from trying that. However, I get an error from the subprocess that tries to install pymssql. `Command failed: python python -m pip install pymssql exited with non zero status.` Do you happen to know why this is the case? If not, I will ask a new question.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is an option to see the full output of the pip command to see what failed exactly. That could give you a clue. The pip command would fail if there are some non-pip-installable dependencies of if you are missing non-python libraries/compilers. I checked for your package, and per http://pymssql.org/en/stable/intro.html, you need to install freetds on your system.

Comment: I needed to install Cython first - with the same procedure. The somehow this dependency was not installed automatically.